# How to create Multiple Choice answer IBM Watson Dialog?

Tags: xml, ibm-watson, watson-dialog, nl-classifier

I have set of questions Yes or No and Some of Questions Multiple Choice

Could you Please help me How to Create Dialog xml file for Multiple Choice Question

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will require some custom formatting from your application. You would need to wrap the potential answers in some sort of tags to create the UI you want.

As I'm sure you've noticed, Dialog will send whatever you want back through in the JSON response. So you could create some custom tags, for example, you might make something up like this:

```
What is my name?
<OptionA>Mitch</OptionA>
<OptionB>Mitchell</OptionB>
<OptionC>Mitchie</OptionC>
<OptionD>M</OptionD>
```

And your UI would know to find those formatting tags and create the multiple choice form you are looking for. Any formatting must be custom made in your app.